# Change to secondary camera using Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, ipad-2

I'm using phonegap 1.2 in a ipad2 app. I need to use the camera facing front, not the main camera. When the API activates the camera it starts ok, but it uses then main camera on the  back, and the user has to switch to the secondary camera in the front. I can't find any parameters in the Phonegap API that can select which camera to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not one of the PhoneGap's features for the moment. I suggest you take this up to the github issue tracker for iOS of it's something you are interested.